# iBeacons: cordova implementation (ios): what are the best practices for background detection

Tags: cordova, app-store, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

Apples' iBeacon tech allows for detection regardless of the apps state: foreground, background or killed or system restart. Is there a best practices way of doing this, as to minimize app-store-submission rejection? I have installed a plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) which allows for background processes - and it works perfectly* (clarification below), but there are plenty of posts saying this will likely result in rejection from apple.

- *By perfectly I mean that it works when the app is pushed to the background, killed and even after the phone was restarted. It's hard to confirm but I think that iOS is killing it off after a certain amount of time. I am getting inconsistent results...*

I also understand that with iOS memory management it will auto-kill my bg-processes if my app is using alot of memory when not in the foreground.

Assuming for a moment that my app does NOT consume 'too much' memory...

It would seem the whole value of having iBeacons is trivialized if the phone can't have access to detection regardless of the app state. I understand that I will need to make a case to apple for why my app would need this functionality. But that would seem to be rhetorical - I need the functionality to use the technology that you (Apple) provide - the value of iBeacons drops significantly if you have to always prime your phone to get them (Beyond that first app launch that gets permissions for requestAlwaysAuthorization)

Am I fretting needlessly? I don't want to take this development all the way to perfection only to find out I won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that native iOS code (Swift or Objective C) can make use of the iOS `CoreLocation` framework's ability to detect beacons even when the app is not running at all.  `CoreLocation` does this by remembering which beacon regions the app is monitoring and auto launching the app if it is not running when the beacon is encountered.  Apple designed this mechanism and approved of its use, and it is how background beacon detection apps generally get into the AppStore.

This is very different than the way the cordova-plugin-backgroun-mode plugin works.  As the README for the plugin notes, Apple reviewers will likely not approve an app that keeps itself continually alive in the background.  **You are right to be concerned.**

Your best bet, other than rewriting your app to be all native, may be to make it a hybrid app.  Rely on native code only for background beacon detections, then use Cordova for the foreground UI after it is launched or resumed.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Please indulge me once more with this scenario. At each launch the app will retrieve server-data for the all beacons within a reasonable GPS radius that we store remotely (custom messaging etc) and store it in a local SQLLite DB. Then following your advice, we'll have some native code in the app to be beacon-aware at all times. When that code is triggered, it will open the app momentarily, trigger some method to get the SQL data and thereby have context to display the beacon messaging via a local notification. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I do not think you can "open the app momentarily".  On native beacon detection in the background, you can run native code for about 5 seconds, but you cannot launch any UI, so I do not think you can run JS code in a Cordova container.  You would have to get the SQL data for the local notification natively.

Comment: I see... so my assumption that I will be able to execute anything from my code in this process is incorrect. The whole can of worms - iBeacon detection, SQL retrieval and the accompanying local push notification will all have to happen in native code. Yikes. Interested in a little project? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that is correct.  If you do end up needing help with the project, there is contact info on my profile page.

Comment: Thanks. I just sent an email. Please respond when you have time or if interested. Cheers!